# Efficient way to group incoming binary inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I've a source that produces string of binary outputs in the form of `000, 001, 010, 000` randomly.

I'd like some hash or clustering program that puts the inputs into groups depending on the number of bits that are different from the other inputs e.g for stream of inputs 000, 001, and 010 should all go to the same bucket/cluster since they differ by one bit.

My initial thinking was to group the first contiguous bits of inputs into one e.g from

```
000
001
010
```

into one. Then then next ones as:

```
011
100
101
```

etc

But I soon realized there are similarities between boundaries, like `000` and `1000` should belong to the same bucket while `011` and `000` should be in different buckets.

How could I approach this? Hints?

James

Comment: If you google "online clustering", that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Isn't this mathematically infeasable. Please correct me if I misunderstood you: You want "000" and "010" in the same bucket (one bit difference). You want "010" and "011" in the same bucket (one bit difference). Hence "000" and "011" would also be in the same bucket, but this is not permitted according to your spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use **gray codes**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

> The reflected binary code, also known as Gray code after Frank Gray, is a binary numeral system where two successive values differ in only one bit.

This results in the following order for three bits (and the associated integers - this is *not* the default binary encoding!):

```
000  = 0
001  = 1
011  = 2
010  = 3
110  = 4
111  = 5
101  = 6
100  = 7
```

And then just split the data in the desired number of buckets linearly.

Alternatively, you may want to look at checksums and error correcting codes, too.

Comment: @NPE,@Anony-Mousse Thanks both. I read a bit online and found I could try the XOR function. e.g if the number of differing bits were to be 2, then XOR would cluster the inputs as below: `(000,011,101,110)` and `(001,010, 100, 111)` since their corresponding XOR functions would produce 2 bits of 1's. My problem then is still how I can using this technique so that as new binary streams arrive, they're directed to their valid clusters

Comment: Well, then *try gray codes*. Map the bit string to the integer, and use `decode(bitstring) / bucketsize` as bucket number...

Comment: I will try that and update tomorrow. It's almost mid-night here

Comment: Just so I get it clearer, I should convert the binary into gray code, then get its integer value, and use the integer value for hashing purposes?

Comment: If the bit string isn't already an integer, convert it to integer. Then decode it from a gray coded integer to a native system integer (so you can do math with it). Just try it out on the example above... the bit strings should give you your desired result, probably you want the first three to become 0, the next three to become 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for your special case I did not figure out a function but here you can have some inspiration:

if you want to have a bucket function that depends on one number you could do something like this:

```
def bucket(i):
    bucket = 0
    bit = 1
    while bit <= i:
        if bit & i > 0:
            bucket += 1
        bit <<= 1 # shift the bit 1 higher
    return bucket
```

if you have two numbers dependent:

```
def bucket(i, x):
    # perform some operation, store it in i
    bucket = 0
    bit = 1
    while bit <= i:
        # you can compare bits here
        if bit & i > 0:
            bucket += 1
    bit <<= 1
    return bucket
```

This is how you can do bitwise bucketing

```
buckets = {}
for number in numbers:
    numberBucket = bucket(number)
    buckets.setdefault(numberBucket, [])
    buckets[numberBucket].append(number)
```